# Why does my Qlima™ portable gas heater shut itself off?

Tags: heater

Just brought Qlima gas heater with flame effect.  It starts out ok, but after few hours, the flames turn blue and the heater turns off.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Does it have a CO2 sensor? to turn it off if the level gets too high?

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? Since the question describes a problem I reversed it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Qlima website](https://www.qlima.com/assortment/heating/gas-heaters), the heater is equipped with oxygen depletion sensors (ODS). These sensors can tell how much oxygen is left in the air. If the oxygen level decreases then this activates the sensor and the gas shuts off to the logs.